# Define Conformal Metric in xAct

Tags: evaluation, xact

For my thesis, I'm reproducing the results of a paper [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.2254) by Alic et al in Mathematica using the package `xAct`.

I'm able to reproduce the standard $3+1$ decomposition given in equations $(6-9)$, but the pain comes from deriving the conformal $3+1$ decomposition, i.e. equations $(14-19)$. To start, I have rather no idea how to define a conformal metric. I spent some time on the famous Internet that inspired me to try the following, based on [this](https://groups.google.com/g/xact/c/VvGfRjQzdQA):

```
DefTensor[phi[], M, PrintAs -> "\[Phi]"]
DefMetric[+1, 
 gammabar[-a, -b], cdbar, {",", 
  "\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(D\), \(_\)]\)"}, 
 ConformalTo -> {gamma[-a, -b], (phi[])^2}, 
 PrintAs -> "\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(\[Gamma]\), \(_\)]\)"]
```

xAct already warns me that this is probably not well-defined as earlier in my notebook, giving the warning `** MakeRule: Potential problems moving indices on the LHS.`. This is because I have some `MakeRule` commands earlier in my notebook.

Nonetheless, I continued, by performing the following command (with a view to deriving equations $(11-12)$ of the paper by Alic)

```
NoScalar[ChangeCurvature[Riccicdbar[-a,-b], cdbar, cd] /. ConformalRules[gammabar, gamma]]
```

However, this resulted in yet more errors:[image]

This convinced me that this is probably not the correct way, hence my question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, the xact github page has an examples section at this [page](https://github.com/xAct-contrib/examples). One of the examples is on Einstein conformal equations [here](https://github.com/xAct-contrib/examples/blob/master/ConformalEinsteinEqs.nb) which you can copy paste to an empty file and name it something like ConformalEq.nb and then open it in Mathematica

Comment: In the examples section there is also an example on conformal transformations apparently.

Comment: i should mention that I have not read those notebooks myself and do not work with conformal transformations. I am just referencing some links that could be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This is not yet an answer, but let me point out some things and suggestions:

First, we need to have full inputs to understand the situation you are. For example, I don't understand why you need two metrics (metric and gamma) before defining the conformal metric gammabar. I'd recommend to work with a conformal metric gammabar that is conformal to a first metric gamma.

For example:

```
<< xAct`xTensor`
$PrePrint = ScreenDollarIndices;
DefManifold[M, 4, {a, b, c, d, f}]
DefMetric[1, gamma[-a, -b], cd, {";", "D"}]
```

Now define gammabar in terms of gamma:

```
DefTensor[phi[], M]
DefMetric[1, gammabar[-a, -b], cdbar, {",", "Dbar"}, ConformalTo -> {gamma[-a, -b], phi[]^2}]
```

You can now perform a change like this:

```
ChangeCurvature[Riccicdbar[-a, -b], cdbar, cd]
```

and then expand the Christoffel terms as derivatives of the conformal factor:

```
ChristoffelToGradConformal[%, gammabar, gamma] // Expand
```

Recall that in xAct we always raise and lower indices with the first metric (i.e. gamma in this case) not with gammabar.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The reason that I defined the metric "metric" is because this is the standard four dimensional metric. Then, I decompose spacetime into an union of hypersurfaces, leading to the three-dimensional metric "gamma" on each hypersurface. Now I want to apply a conformal transformation on the metric "gamma" leading to the metric "gammabar". The reason that I do this all in one notebook is such that I don't lose all the definitions and built-in relations (such as the normal vector, extrinsic curvature,...).